# When we use adb devices ,console show a smiley face

Tags: android

[image]

This happens during STS testing。

```
run sts-engbuild -m CtsSecurityTestCases -t android.security.cts.StagefrightTest#testStagefright_cve_2019_2334 -o -d
```

After the device reboot，using adb devices, the console shows a small face. And we can not do sts again. We find that STS test tool can not find the devices.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect to the device with adb shell and run: 'getprop' to find a list of properties.

Then look for the one with a smiley face :)

Could be something like: persist.usb.serialno or maybe some other property in the most recent version.
Either way, someone in your test is likely changing it, so you should then analyze who is updating the property.